# CodeIgniter: Returning data as an object vs array

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

There are functions to return your data as either an object:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```

Or an array:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

I've always returned my data as arrays, but when is a case that returning an "object" is preferable?

Comment: It's 100% up to you.  Whichever you prefer is your choice.

Comment: Interesting, I figured there would have been certain cases where each one is useful

Comment: Maybe if you have a library that expects the data in a specific format?  But, otherwise the only "useful" case is if you like objects and the `->` operator :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer an array when there are multiple rows and an object when there is a single record returned.  I often ask myself a few questions like:

- Does it need to be in a particular order? ***Array***
- Am I going to output for an API? ***Objects***
- Is this a list of elements with properties? ***Array of Objects***
- Who am I delivering data to? Do they work with Arrays or Objects?